# How to use ModalPopupExtender to redirect to another webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender

ModalPopupExtender has PopupControlID to control what panel to popup. But I do not want to make a panel in the same page, is there a way to [pop up another webpage?
Like I have register button on my default.aspx. Once I click register button I want to popup register.aspx page. How can I achieve this? Thanks~

Answer (score -1):

do achive this functionality put an iframe inside the panel and change the source of iframe programatically using javascript